# Sharing data with multiple triggers

Tags: rust

I'm using cursive, that implements triggers for catching certain keys.
I have to manage all the Fn keys and ESC, so i need to setup multiple triggers with the same code, and i have to have in a variable the code of the key.

```
set_trigger (Key::F1, cursive);
set_trigger (Key::F2, cursive);
..
set_trigger (Key::Esc, cursive);

fn set_trigger(key: Key, mut cursive: Cursive) {
    cursive.set_on_pre_event(key, move |s| {
        s.quit(); // exits the cursive session
    });
}
```

i thought about passing to set_trigger() a Rc<Cell> that is filled, when triggered, with the code of the key pressed.
is it an acceptable way to manage this situation?
What could be a "idiomatic" way?

I think that Rc<Cell> is not so good.

Comment: "is it an acceptable way to manage this situation" is pretty dependent on the situation. `Rc<Cell<bool>>` can work as a one-off, but its hard to tell if there is a better way without any context.

Comment: The real question is not how to capture this data, but how it's used. That dictates the best storage mechanism.